# how to Transmit data with the URL

Tags: php, html

I want to delete a row known by its id 
this is my code

```
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Nom etudiant</th>
                <th>Prenom etudiant</th>
                <th>CNE</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
            <?php 
                foreach ($results as $r) { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $r[0] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $r[1]; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $r[2]; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $r[3]; ?></td>
                        <td> <a href="supprimer_etu.php?ID_etudiant=$r[0]">Supprimer </a></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php } ?>
    </table>
```

file supprimer_etu.php

```
<?php require_once("classes.php"); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    try {
        $dsn="mysql:local=localhost;dbname=tp3_php";
        $user="root";
        $pass="";
            $bdd = new PDO($dsn,$user,$pass);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    try {
            $id=$_GET['ID_etudiant'];
            $sql7 ="DELETE FROM etudiant where ID_etudiant='.$id.'";
            $stmt = $bdd->exec($sql7);


        } catch (Exception $e) {
            die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

the problem is : when i try to delete a row , it does not work (supprimer_etu.php?ID_etudiant=$r[0]) $r[0] don't change 
the url of supprimer.php file is (http://localhost/Travail/DAO/supprimer_etu.php?ID_etudiant=$r[0])

Comment: Try changing this `<a href="supprimer_etu.php?ID_etudiant=$r[0]">` to `<a href="supprimer_etu.php?ID_etudiant='"<?php echo $r[0] ?>'>`

Comment: thank you @blurfus it's worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to echo the value for the url change your url to

```
<td><a href="supprimer_etu.php?ID_etudiant=<?php echo $r[0]; ?>">Supprimer </a></td>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are simply appending `$r[0]` to the URL instead of appending the value of the variable.

Use this updated code:

```php
<tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Nom etudiant</th>
    <th>Prenom etudiant</th>
    <th>CNE</th>
    <th>Action</th>
</tr>
<?php foreach ($results as $r) { ?>
   <tr>
       <td><?php echo $r[0] ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $r[1]; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $r[2]; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $r[3]; ?></td>
       <td>
           <a href="supprimer_etu.php?ID_etudiant=<?php echo $r[0]; ?>">
              Supprimer
           </a>
       </td>
   </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

The change I have made is in this line of code:

```
<td>
    <a href="supprimer_etu.php?ID_etudiant=<?php echo $r[0]; ?>">Supprimer </a>
</td>
```